# Don't understand why this AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'merge_one' is occurring

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm following a tutorial, and I'm using the last python2 (homebrew) with PyCharm (with project interpreter configured) - But I'm stuck in this part:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph()
nicole = Node("Person", name="Nicole")
graph.create(nicole)
graph.delete(nicole)
nicole = graph.merge_one("Person", "name", "Nicole")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'merge_one'
```

I already checked the [documentation](https://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html?highlight=merge) and it seems that I'm doing everything ok . I tried to uninstall and install last version of py2neo but with no success. How I solve this problem?

Expected behavior: Running that command from the python2 console: If that Person exists don't duplicate it but change its values, if don't exist create it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but from the documentation it says Neo4j has an _optional_ scheme database. so you may have to be using it for the `merge_one` method to exist.

Comment: I tried using `graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("Person", "name")` , the command successful runs, but didn't solve the other _merge_one_ problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fastly ended up using the version 4 as opposed to 2. So using Graph.merge, solved the problem:

```
jonh = Node("Person", name="Jonh", age = 21)
graph.create(jonh)
ana = Node("Person", name="Ana", age = 44)
graph.create(ana)
michael = Node("Person", name="Ana", age = 33)
graph.merge(michael, "Person", "name") # So the age of Ana will change to 33, as expected.
```

For using the commands related to my question, the version 2 must be installed, for eg. directly from py2neo repo:

```
pip install https://github.com/technige/py2neo/archive/release/2.0.7.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting [the source code](https://github.com/technige/py2neo/blob/v4.2/py2neo/database.py), I think the function you're looking for is `Graph.match_one`. There is also a function `Graph.merge`, but that doesn't take `Node` as an argument.